# Get type of underlying class from a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, types

I've got some classes which inherit the same interface `IParsee`. They all have `[Regex]` attribute. I need to make a `Parser` class to which I pass a string and an array of delegates to parse the given string and return an array of `IParsee` objects. The problem is that I want to keep the code dry and not to write a method for matching string in every `IParsee` class, but I want to write it in a `Parser` class. I do not know how to get the type of class by its method. I saw that I can call `GetType()` on method, but my method throws an error if a wrong string to parse was given.

Method in `Parser`:

```
public class Parser
{
    public static List<IParsee> Parse(String text, params Func<String, IParsee>[] meth)
{
        List<IParsee> list = new List<IParsee>();
        IParsee res;
        for (int i = 0; i < meth.Length; i++)    
            // here i want to get the regex attribute and the MatchCollection
            // looping through the MatchCollection parsing 
            // every match and pushing it to the list

        return list;
}
```

Method in class which I need to be parsed:

```
[RegexAttribute(@"\w+\s\w+\swas\sborn\son\s(\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d)"]
public class Person : IParsee
{
   public static IParsee Parse(string str)
   {
```

So I call it

```
List<IParsee> l = Parser.Parse(person.ToString(), Person.Parse);
```

Comment: It's not clear how you want to use it. Please extend your question with implementations of `Parser.Parse` and `Person.Parse`. Pseudocode at least.

Comment: Do you want to access the attribute value of `RegexAttribute` from inside the method `Parser.Parse` by accessing the type of the method sent in the list of `Func<String, IParsee>` ?

Comment: @OndrejTucny I added some more explanation and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each delegate has a [`Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx) property that gives you access to the `MethodInfo` instance holding all metadata about the method referenced by the delegate. To get access to this property, you have to cast the `Func<T,TResult>` to a [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx). Then from [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it's easy to get the [`DeclaringType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Type methodClass = ((Delegate)meth[i]).Method.DeclaringType
```

Now from `methodClass` you can retrieve the attribute:

```
RegexAttribute attr = (RegexAttribute)methodClass.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(RegexAttribute));
```

Note: If the `Parse` method were not static, you'd use [`Delegate.Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get access to the actual instance. Hence the `[Regex]` attribute would have to be declared on a descendant class and it would still work.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer )

Comment: @AleksandrGrebenskiy You are welcome. You should then accept the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the declaring type of the method passed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meth.Length; i++)
{
    RegexAttribute attribute = meth[i].GetMethodInfo().DeclaringType
                                .GetCustomAttribute<RegexAttribute>();

    // assume you have a property called YourStringProperty in RegexAttribute
    string regexAttributeValue = attribute.YourStringProperty;
}
```

`DeclaringType` means the class (type) on which the method was defined.

`GetCustomAttribute` is used to get attribute tagged on Methods or Classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer